# Use of undefined constant ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH - assumed 'ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH'

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, array-filter

I use Codeigniter as the framework and create an array like below using input parameters from a form.

```
$data           = array(
    'generated_id'      => $this->input->post('generated_id'),
    'one'               => $this->input->post('one'),
    'two'               => $this->input->post('two'),
    'three'             => $this->input->post('three'),
    'modified_date'     => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    'modified_user_id'  => $this->session->userdata('user_id')
);
```

What I want to do is if the value from the input fields are empty I want to set the value of the particular array position to NULL.
I'm using below function to get it done.

```
$data = array_filter($data,function($value, $key){
    if(empty($value))
        return NULL;
    else
        return $value;
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH);
```

But I end up with below error.

```
Use of undefined constant ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH - assumed 'ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH'
```

Is there an easy way to get this done or how can I fix this?

Comment: The `ARRAY_FILTER_` flags were introduced in PHP version 5.6.

Comment: On the top of my head, do you have PHP `5.6.0` or higher? If you don't `ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH` and `ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY` don't work.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. if that so how can I fix this?. I'm using PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.4 (cli) (built: Sep  4 2014 06:56:34)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're not using `$key` in your callback at all, you do not need the `ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH` flag either. Your function can be simplified to:

```
$data = array_filter($data);
```

Seriously, it does the same thing.

> What I want to do is if the value from the input fields are empty I want to set the value of the particular array position to `NULL`.

`array_filter` won't do that to begin with. It will completely remove "empty" elements, not set them to `null`. You want:

```
$data = array_map(function ($value) { return $value ?: null; }, $data);
```

This will set any values which are *falsey* (empty strings, `0`, empty arrays) to `null`.

Comment: Could you please be kind enough to explain how the solution works, array_map? Then I can accept this as well.

Comment: `array_map` is a pretty common operation, which is essentially this: `foreach ($data as &$value) $value = $value ?: null;`